# How to make a function to loop in Android when JSON reply is null

Tags: android, json

.I'm new in Android and I'm using tutorials to learn more. I am trying to create a login page in Android with remote server using PHP and JSON. Below is the function I've been experimenting for logging in. My problem is that whenever I enter a wrong username and password (intentionally, of course), the application is forcefully closed when I use the correct login information next. I think it's because JSON returns null when the wrong login info is used. From there, I don't know how to handle the null return. I tried reading on looper and Async but still no luck yet.

```
void login() {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", EtUsernameInput.getText().toString()));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", EtPasswordInput.getText().toString()));
    String response = null;

    try {
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx/activity1a.php",
                postParameters);
        String result = response.toString(); 

        try {
            returnString = "";
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("log_tag","student_id: "+ json_data.getString("student_id") + ", first_login:  "+ json_data.getString("s_first_login"));

                String first_login = json_data.getString("s_first_login");                  
           }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        if (first_login.equals("") || first_login.equals(null)) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity1_Login.this, "User not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
         } else
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity1_Login.this, Activity2_Main.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString()); 
    }      
}
```

Is there a way for me to go back to the start of the program where the login info is asked whenever a wrong login info is used?
Thanks in advance for the help/advice.

Comment: use the sample code which is available into the android sample

Comment: i see errors in your code, fix them 1st, `Log.i("log_tag","student_id: "+ json_data.getString("student_id") + ", first_login:  + json_data.getString("s_first_login"));`

Comment: Ok. I've changed it to Log.i("log_tag","student_id: "+ json_data.getString("student_id") + ", first_login:  "+ json_data.getString("s_first_login")); Hope that it's correct. Is It?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: **[JSON, PHP, MySQL with AsyncTask ProgressDialog](http://ugirusgiarto.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/json-php-mysql-with-asynctask-progressdialog/)**

Comment: This is among the first samples that I tried but can't make it work. If you have a working version, could you please share? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
 if (first_login == "")
```

with this

```
 if (first_login.equals("")||first_login.equals(null))
```

Comment: I changed the code to if (first_login.equals("")||first_login.equals(null))
            Toast.makeText(Activity1_Login.this, "User not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); However, when I use the wrong login info, it doesn't display the toast. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Where do you call your login() method?
İf it is inside a regular thread or doinBackground it wont work.

Comment: I have placed it inside the setOnClickistener of the login button. The code is as follows:   public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1_Login.this, "", "Validating user...", true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      login();           
     }
    }).start(); 
   }

Comment: Put your toast in   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            
                        }
                    });

Comment: So I use the code: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {Toast.makeText(Activity1_Login.this, "User not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } }); Would this be placed inside the setOnClickListener of the login button or inside the if statement?

Comment: You cant set Views in regular Threads so, put it below if (first_login == "")

Comment: I placed the code below the if statement and it still didn't show when I entered the wrong info. I'll update the code above.

Comment: i checked your answer. Lastly change this  if (first_login == "") with this if (first_login.equals("")||first_login.equals(null))

Comment: Ohhh... sorry about that. Forgot to change that part too. I've updated the code. It works well now. Although I've made adjustments here and there. Thanks again!

Comment: From my post last Sep 19 at 9:08, I mentioned that I placed the login() method inside the setOnClickistener of the login button. My problem now is that when I enter the wrong login info, the progress dialog shows up, then the error message, then the progress dialog comes up again without stopping. Thus, I can't input new login info. How could I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I dont see any progressdialog in your code but you can dismiss the dialog before show and also you should check the dialog before show like ** if (dialog.isShowing()) {
   
  }**